# How can my widget maintain state without use of cookies?

Tags: cookies, browser, local-storage, third-party-cookies

Our widgets rely on cookies: example.com site embeds mywebsite.com in an iframe and customers can use our widget.

With browsers starting to block third party cookies more and more our widget breaks out in to a new page which isn't great and I suspect eventually it will stop working altogether. We are starting to wonder about an alternative way to setting cookies cross domains.

Things like Intercom widgets or live chat widgets can maintain a state and i've never seen them break.

How do they do it?